# passing a rowindex from gridview item click to javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to pass a row index to my javascript function using the below line that resides inside the gridview, but I keep getting an error.

Below is my code.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MCLID"> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <label style="text-decoration: underline"
         onclick="javascript:warningMessage('<%# Eval("ID") %>','<%# Eval("systempath").ToString().Replace("'",@"\'") %>','<%# Eval("root_level") %>','<%# Eval("Parentid") %>','<%# Eval(Container.DataItemIndex +1) %>');"><%#Eval("ID") %></label> 
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Post the relevant part of what you get in the browser (i.e. what does the above actually generate). What error do you get? Where do you get it, on the server or at the client?

Comment: what is the error? Post your js function too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
onclick="javascript:warningMessage('<%# Eval("ID") %>','<%# Eval("systempath").ToString().Replace("'",@"\'") %>','<%# Eval("root_level") %>','<%# Eval("Parentid") %>','<%# Eval(Container.DataItemIndex +1) %>');"
```

Try using something like:

```
onclick='<%# "javascript:warningMessage('" + Eval("ID").ToString() + "'" %>'
```

Comment: Yup, that'd be the problem... premature js eval. Good pickup.